# filling segments by intersection method: there is no named path called

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, fill

I'm just trying to fill each peripheral segment of my drawing. The names of the hexagon and the circle are `test` and `circ`. Additionally, the line pieces connecting edges of the hexagon to the outer circle are named in the for loop. However, when I use the names as the intersection segments, a `there is no named path called '2 and circ and test'` is thrown.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
    fill=red!15,
    draw = black,
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=6,
    align=center,
    minimum size=5cm](test){};

    \node[
    fill=none,
    draw = black,
    circle,
    dashed,
    minimum size=9.2cm](circ){};

    \foreach \n in {1,...,6}
    {
        \draw[black, name path = \n](test.corner \n) --
        ({\n*60}:4.6);
    }

    \node[] (c) at (test.center){$\pi^{0}$};

    \foreach \n in {1,...,6}
    {
        \node[] (\n) at ({\n*60+30}:3.3){$\pi^{\n}$};
    }

    \fill[
    orange!50,
    intersection segments={
        of=1 and 2 and circ and test
    }];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can only compute the intersection segments of two paths, not three, at once.

Comment: @marmot: I have four! What is the doable plan, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, the simplest possibility would be to do

```
\fill[orange] (test.corner 1) -- (60:4.6) arc(60:120:4.6) -- (test.corner 2);
```

However, let's discuss how to build up intersection segments of more than two paths. Just define a new path from the intersection segments of two of the paths, store it as an auxiliary path, and then combine it with the next path, and so on.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[name path=test,
    fill=red!15,
    draw = black,
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=6,
    align=center,
    minimum size=5cm](test){};

    \node[name path=circ,
    fill=none,
    draw = black,
    circle,
    dashed,
    minimum size=9.2cm](circ){};

    \foreach \n in {1,...,6}
    {
        \draw[black, name path = \n](test.corner \n) --
        ({\n*60}:4.6);
    }

    \node (c) at (test.center){$\pi^{0}$};

    \foreach \n in {1,...,6}
    {
        \node[] (\n) at ({\n*60+30}:3.3){$\pi^{\n}$};
    }
    \path [name path=aux1,%draw=blue,thick,->,
    intersection segments={of=1 and circ,
        sequence={L1--R2}}];
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      %\fill[orange] (test.corner 1) -- (60:4.6) arc(60:120:4.6) -- (test.corner 2);
      \path [fill=orange,%draw=red,thick,->,
      intersection segments={of=aux1 and 2,
          sequence={L1--R1[reverse]}}];
    \end{scope} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a beautiful answer! Trivial remark: The `\begin{scope}[on background layer]` could be placed before the `aux1` path is constructed, to ensure that auxiliary path is also on the background layer.